# How to compare two sets of categorical observations?

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I have two strains of organisms, strain A and strain B. Each organism is allowed to move along a closed line segment and is initially positioned at the midpoint of the line segment. After a given amount of time, each organism's position is registered as "right" (movement to the test sector, a nutrient droplet), "left" (movement to the control sector, a water droplet) or "middle" (no movement).

I'm trying to show that strain A has a higher probability of moving to the right, compared to strain B.

What statistical technique should I use to analyze this dataset? Currently, I scored "left", "middle" and "right" as "-1", "0" and "+1", respectively and I applied the Wilcoxon rank sum test in R (`wilcox.test(score ~ strain, data=data)`). However, I'm not sure if this is a valid approach.

This is my data:

```
strain, sector, score
---------------------
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   right   1
A   middle  0
A   middle  0
A   left    -1
B   right   1
B   right   1
B   right   1
B   right   1
B   right   1
B   middle  0
B   middle  0
B   left    -1
B   left    -1
B   left    -1
B   left    -1
B   left    -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your counts are relatively small I would wonder
about the validity of tests based on normal normal approximations.
[Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) uses a hypergeometric distribution.

**Hypergeometric distribution.** Suppose I have 32 balls in an urn, of which 23 are green
and 9 are red. I sample 20 balls at random from the urn
without replacement. What is the probability I get 17 or
more green balls.

The probability of getting *exactly* 17 green balls, as computed in R statistical software (where `dhyper` is a hypergeometric PDF and `phyper` a hypergeometric CDF), is

$$\frac{{23\choose 17}{9 \choose 3}}{32\choose 20} = 0.0376.$$

```
choose(23,17)*choose(9,3)/choose(32, 20)
[1] 0.03755455
dhyper(17,  23,9,  20)
[1] 0.03755455
```

The probability of getting 17 or more green balls is
$$\sum_{k=17}^{20}\frac{{23\choose k}{9 \choose 20-k}}{32\choose 20} = 0.0433.$$

```
sum(dhyper(17:20, 23,9, 20))
[1] 0.04328028
1 - phyper(16, 23,9,  20)
[1] 0.04328028
```

Here is a plot of the relevant hypergeometric distribution:

```
x = 10:20;  pdf = dhyper(x, 23,9, 20)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue", 
     main="Hypergeometric PDF")
  abline(h=0,col="green2")
  abline(v = 16.5, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

**Fisher exact test for your data.** If I counted correctly from the data display in your question,
The 20 balls chosen correspond to Strain A, the green balls
correspond to moving Right, and the red balls to no movement
or moving left.

The null hypothesis is that right movers are equally likely
among A's and B's.
Then the probability $0.0433$ is the P-value
of a one-sided Fisher's exact test for your data. That is, it's
the probability of getting the observed number $k=17$ of
right movers or more, out of the 20 A's.

The null hypothesis is that A's and B's are equally likely to move right. The one-sided alternative is that A's are more likely to move right. Because the P-value is smaller than 5%, the null hypothesis is rejected at the 5% level.

**Test of two proportions.** In R, the procedure `prop.test`, a [test of two binomial proportions](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm), uses a normal approximation
to compare observed fractions of right movers among A's $\hat p_A = 17/20 = 0.85$ and among B's $\hat p_B = 6/12 = 0.50.$  But there is a warning
message that the P-value may not be exactly correct. [A chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom is the same as the square of
a standard normal distribution; this accounts for the reference
to chi-squared in the output.]

```
        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(17, 6) out of c(20, 12)
X-squared = 2.9784, df = 1, p-value = 0.04219
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01201557 1.00000000
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.85   0.50 

Warning message:
In prop.test(c(17, 6), c(20, 12), alte = "g") :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```